# Why is `const enum` allowed with `isolatedModules`?

Tags: typescript

```
declare const enum {
    UP,
    DOWN,
}`
```

isn't allowed when the `--isolatedModules` compilerOption is used.

```
error TS1209: Ambient const enums are not allowed when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.
```

My understanding of `--isolatedModules` is that it tells the compiler to do extra checking to ensure that separate compilation (such as by using [`transpileModule`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#transpiling-a-single-file)) is safe.

So why is `const enum` (without `declare`) allowed? Isn't it unsafe for separate compilation? That is, if `foo.ts` imports and uses a `const enum` from `bar.ts`, how could `ts.transpileModule` know how to correctly transpile the enum usage?

Answer (score 22):

If you are using other transpilers to compile your code, for example babel, then that transpiler can only work with typescript declared in the same module file. If you declaring your const enum inside the same module that you are using it, then it's not a problem. The problem start when you want to expose your enum to other modules.

For example, if you are writing an enum:

```
const enum Animal {
  DOG,
  CAT
}
```

So far it's not a problem if you will just use this code in the SAME source file that you declare it:

```
Animal.DOG // Will be replaced with 0.
```

But imagine that you want to use Animal.DOG in another source file. With transpiler compilation happening on an isolated-module basis:

- the compiler reads a typescript module.
- the module’s type information is stripped.
- what’s left is the JavaScript module that the compiler writes.

so it's not possible to know what is Animal.DOG if it's not been declared on the same module. That's why the flag is called --isolatedModules in the first place. This flag is checking and reporting any typescript use that'll not work in this case.

If you are writing a library then DON'T export const enum because your users will not be able to use them if they are using babel to compile their code instead of tsc.

Comment: This answer is amazing and led me to find this article which explains this (frustrating) problem in more depth: https://ncjamieson.com/dont-export-const-enums/

Answer (score 2):

You can't use enum because the transpiler will convert the value to a number and this provokes issues in occassions.

An alternative to having something 'enum like' that gives you type checking and value autocompletion is **to create an object with the keys-values and create a 'type' from the object keys**.

The code for that is the following:

1- In the "declaration_file.ts", we create the `{} as const` and the `type`

```
//'enum like' object declaration (notice the `as const` at the end)
export const Strategy = {
    STRATEGY1: "STRATEGY1",
    STRATEGY2: "STRATEGY2",
    STRATEGY3: "STRATEGY3"
} as const;

//'enum like' "TS type" creation
export type StrategyType = keyof typeof Strategy;
```

2- Then, to use it (in another file/repo) we import both (or just the one you need) and use it

```
import { Strategy, StrategyType } from 'declaration_file';

//'enum like' type and value assignation
let myStrategy: StrategyType;    //type
myStrategy = Strategy.STRATEGY3; //value
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was why const enums *are* allowed with isolatedModules. You gave a helpful answer to a different question, and fwiw I agree with your choice of enum encoding https://maxheiber.medium.com/alternatives-to-typescript-enums-50e4c16600b1

Comment: Hi @MaxHeiber, this answer was just to provide an alternative that can be useful on some occasions, it was not intended for exactly your question but for future readers ;)