# Why is `const enum` allowed with `isolatedModules` in non module file

Tags: typescript

I already know [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854964/why-is-const-enum-allowed-with-isolatedmodules). But its answer did not help me.

I am curious as to why the following scenario does not seem to violate the isolatedModules constraint in relation to const enum.

In my tsconfig, I have isolatedModules set to true.

The content of a.ts is as follows:

```js
const enum MyEnum {
  SomeValue
};
```

The content of b.ts is as follows:

```js
console.log(MyEnum.SomeValue);
```

By default, there is no error shown in tsc for this. However, as you might expect, transpiling produces a reference error.

To my understanding, the isolatedModules option was introduced to address issues like this. Its main function is to enforce constraints that ensure each file can be transpiled independently by the transpiler. This allows each file to be processed independently, without needing type information from the whole project.

However, both TypeScript's official documentation and actual implementations mention that the usage of namespace and ambient const enum would violate this, but there's no mention about const enum.
Can someone clarify what I might be missing here?

I know that:

• A TypeScript file without export is treated as a global script file.

• So, there is an option, moduleDetection: force, to enforce this.

• When isolatedModules is enabled, preserveConstEnums is also enabled, which prevents const enums from being inlined.

I don't understand that:

• Why there is no error when a TypeScript file without export, which contains a const enum, is within a project that only has isolatedModules enabled, even when another file references it.

Comment: so isn't this the IDE's fault instead?

Comment: (Additional) The problem does not occur in the results of tsc as well as the IDE.

I replaced IDE to tsc